# Coloring 3 menu bars

Tags: website-design, color, color-theory

I'm trying to design my own website and i choosed content background color light grey an items white to focus attention but I'm having hard time to find best colors for 3-bar-menu.

[image]
[image]

Top menu bar is for choosing page secion or "App" (Classifieds, Dating, Catalog, Recipes, Forum)

I wan't users to focus on Second and Third menu but easly find Top menu if they want to switch page sections.

I can't find best color scheme. Should it be Dark Light Dark or Darkest Lighter Lightest..

Please suggest what is the proper way to choose colors for my menu bars.

Also all suggestions regards UX are welcome!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you (or someone) please provide an English version of the menus? or at least a translation of what the second and third level menus say? It would be very helpful to see some actual content that may be in the third level

Comment: Cant edit my own post but here is English version http://i.imgur.com/1NJvOIi.png

Basicly third menu will be categories of classifieds.

Answer (score 3):

**You shouldn't need to make this decision at all**. What I mean by that is that you shouldn't have three menus like this in the first place, it's terrible design and UX. It takes up way too much visual space and I can't even imagine how it would look on a phone.

As such, you really should think very hard about how you can avoid showing all of these menus, especially at all times. I can't provide much detail past that currently as I don't speak the language used in the photo and you aren't using real content, but I am sure that you can combine the menus better than you currently are.

Once you update the question with more information I will likely add more to this answer.

Comment: Well I was inspired by [link](Themeforest.com) becouse they had delt with similar problem..

This is my design translated to english http://i.imgur.com/1NJvOIi.png

Answer (score 0):

If you are not to inclined towards green I could suggest you to use a vibrant blue (#307ee7) on background and  white (#FFFFFF) for text color.

In that case for the topmost bar you can use a darker tone of blue (#1b4072) as background and and a less prominent white for text, say rgba(255,255,255,.8).

Even you are using green - I would suggest a vibrant green (#70c829). And always a white text on a dark vibrant background.

However I agree to the point that so many items in one menu bar might not look good. I mean a off canvas menu or a sidebar could be a better option.